# how to fix Laravel Error when executing the route

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have following link in blade file for the edit page

```
<a href="{{route('topic.edit'}}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

and my controller is as following

```
public function edit()
    {
        return view('topic.edit');
    }
```

and route is

```
Route::resource('topic','TopicController');
```

but got following error message
`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or '`

how to fix this problem?

Comment: you have a syntax error on your code.. i think it is on `<a href="{{route('topic.edit'}}" ...`, the closing parenthesis is missing `<a href="{{route('topic.edit')}}"...`

Comment: yes it is true here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a closing parenthesis missing in your code

```
<a href="{{route('topic.edit'}}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

Just fix it:

```
<a href="{{route('topic.edit')}}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Edit</a>
```